# is createFragment() method in android world?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

try to use createFragment(). but android studio unable to recognize it. line #19. do i have to import something to use createFragment();

```
package com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

/**
 * Created by simerpreetjassal on 16-07-30.
 */
public class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment=fm.findFragmentById(R.id.framgment_container);
        if(fragment==null){
            fragment= createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.framgment_container,fragment).commit();
        }
    }


}
```

similarly
android studio unable to recognize @override method named createFragment() method in following class. which is child of above class. Little frustrated.

```
package com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class CrimeActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment(){
        return new CrimeFragment();
    }

}
```

Comment: * new Fragment(); you mean?

Comment: no... following one book name big nerd ranch .they were using it.

Comment: Oh that book. Yeah, it does uses a pattern for creating fragments which is introduced in the beginning and it'll be used everywhere. You definitely skipped a chapter man.

Comment: can you suggest any good book to learn android.

Comment: At your level, Big nerd ranch I believe is the best. Read it from the beginning and keep building stuff and while you do that make it a habit to read official code and documentation

Answer (score 0):

Little idea here,
In Android there are two different methods to create fragment:

- static method
- dynamic method

Static method is when we “write” directly our fragment in XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment android:id="@+id/listFragment"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
class="com.survivingwithandroid.fragment.LinkListFragment"
android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this case our layout isn’t dynamic because we can’t manage the fragment at runtime. 
`FrameLayout` we can handle fragments as we need at runtime, but to do it we need a `manager`.
This is `FragmentManager`.

This component can

- add
- replace
- remove fragments at runtime.

if we want to make our layout dynamic,we have to use `FrameLayout`.

```
private FrameLayout frameLayoutForFragment;
    // i use this frame to do my transactions between fragments 
    frameLayoutForFragment = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    GalleryFragment galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            frameLayoutForFragment.removeAllViews();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, galleryFragment).addToBackStack( "tag" );
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Note :

inside the transaction you can do above 3 things.

```
`android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`
```

is used because your activity extends `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You miss the code which should be above onCreate method.

```
protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
```

U could check this code in the book 210p. The code is highlighted.